# Is it possible to flatten MongoDB result query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, flatten

I have a deeply nested collection in my MongoDB collection.

When I run the following query:

```
db.countries.findOne({},{'data.country.neighbor.name':1,'_id':0})
```

I end up with this nested result here:

```
{"data" : {
  "country" : [
    {
      "neighbor" : [
        {
          "name" : "Austria"
        },
        {
          "name" : "Switzerland"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "neighbor" : {
        "name" : "Malaysia"
      }
    },
    {
      "neighbor" : [
        {
          "name" : "Costa Rica"
        },
        {
          "name" : "Colombia"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}}
```

Now, this is what I want:

```
['Austria', 'Switzerland', 'Malaysia', 'Costa Rica', 'Colombia']
```

or this:

```
{'name':['Austria', 'Switzerland', 'Malaysia', 'Costa Rica', 'Colombia']}
```

or anything else similar...  Is this possible?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can use `$project` & `$unwind` & `$group` of [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) framework to get the result closer to your requirement.

```
> db.countries.aggregate({$project:{a:'$data.country.neighbor.name'}},
                         {$unwind:'$a'},
                         {$unwind:'$a'},
                         {$group:{_id:'a',res:{$addToSet:'$a'}}})
  {
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : "a",
            "res" : [
                "Colombia",
                "Malaysia",
                "Switzerland",
                "Costa Rica",
                "Austria"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

`$unwind` used twice since the name array is nested deep. And It will only work if the `neighbor` attribute is an array. In your example one neighbor field (Malaysia) is not an array

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting the following though: `{ "result" : [ ], "ok" : 1 }` :/

Comment: Interesting. It still feels like a lot of work but I guess that I'll just have to get used to it. Thanks

Comment: Seeing this 5 years after the fact... Mongo - which I love - is still ****ing bizarre.

Answer (score 13):

Done it much simpler way, maybe it is recent

```
db.countries.aggregate({$unwind:'$data.country.neighbor.name'})
```

Answer (score 2):

To flatten your data you can also use `$reduce`. [Here is an example in the docs.](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/#array-concatenation)

```js
db.countries.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      newField: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$data.country.neighbor.name",
          initialValue: [],
          in: { $concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this"] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score -7):

It's pretty straightforward under the new [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/). The $project and $unwind operation are right for the purpose.